# <script> tag vs <script type = 'text/javascript'> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I was just wondering, what is the difference between

```
<script>
```

and

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
```

Is it different for different webservers?

For example,(I know it's incorrect to provide a link from w3schools, but look)

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst

Using chrome, I visited w3schools and I realised that the `<script>` tag is all I need.

However, when I did an offline javascript test, i realised that i need the

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
```

tag. Why is this so?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 My question is different. I asked if it is affected by different web servers

Comment: It is a duplicate, and this does not depend on the web server. If you think you need the attribute in an offline test, then you should present ask about *that* specifically and provide code that demonstrates what you mean (and explain why you think you “need” it).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela nope. I specified my own problem too.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

> In HTML 4, the type attribute is required. In my experience, all
>   browsers will default to text/javascript if it is absent, but that
>   behaviour is not defined anywhere. While you can in theory leave it
>   out and assume it will be interpreted as JavaScript, it's invalid
>   HTML, so why not add it.
>
> In HTML 5, the type attribute is optional and defaults to
>   text/javascript

Use `<script type="text/javascript">` or simply `<script>` (if omitted, the type is the same). Do not use `<script language="JavaScript">`; the language attribute is deprecated

**Ref** :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65aaf5f3-09db-4f7e-a32d-d53e9720ad4c/script-languagejavascript-or-script-typetextjavascript-?forum=netfxjscript
and
[Difference between <script> tag with type and <script> without type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659029/difference-between-script-tag-with-type-and-script-without-type)

Do you need type attribute at all?

I am using HTML5- No

I am not using HTML5 - Yes

Comment: But why doesn't w3schools try-it-editor require the whole line?

Comment: Are you quoting that text from something?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit Please quote the source as well. Now people might think that, these are your own words.

Comment: Can you tell me where you got that from?

Comment: Check now @thefourtheye

Comment: This does not answer any of the questions asked. Accepting it means that the question was intended to ask something it did not.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't get you what you are trying to say

Comment: This does not answer the question “What is the difference...” (the difference is that one of the tags has an attribute that the other one does not have) or the question “Is it different for different webservers?” or the question “Why is this so?” (whatever that might mean).

Comment: Its not about webservers its about browser support that client is using

Comment: means `type` is just to define script type. And `text/javascript` will be taken by default?

Comment: But what about browser support? Do IE7 ou 8 support `<script>`?

Comment: @Justcode thanks, but it doesn't mention IE8 support when there is no `type` attribute AFAICT.

Comment: Hey people! I saw in w3school the following: "The media type consists of two parts: one media type and one subtype. For JavaScript, the media type is 'application/javascript'." So, what is the difference between "text/javascript" and "application/javascript"?     Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp

Comment: @LuizaRodrigues text/javascript is obsolete always use application/javascript when you want to. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21098951/2630817

Answer (score 30):

`<script>` is HTML 5.

`<script type='text/javascript'>` is HTML 4.x (and XHTML 1.x).

`<script language="javascript">` is HTML 3.2.

> Is it different for different webservers?

No.

> when I did an offline javascript test, i realised that i need the `<script type = 'text/javascript'>` tag.

That isn't the case. Something else must have been wrong with your test case.

Answer (score 13):

[Douglas Crockford says](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html):

> `type="text/javascript"`
>
> This attribute is optional. Since
>   Netscape 2, the default programming
>   language in all browsers has been
>   JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute
>   is required and unnecessary. In HTML,
>   it is better to leave it out. The
>   browser knows what to do.

In HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1(.1), the `type` attribute for `<script>` elements is [required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT).

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: @leonneo — There's a link in the answer.

Comment: @leonneo taken from http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html as added link at top.

Comment: Just to clarify: Crockford is talking about *making it work*, as opposed to *making it valid*.

Comment: You had me at Douglas.

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- HTML4 and (x)HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- HTML5 -->
<script></script>
```

**type**
    attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute. This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript. If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score -2):

You only need **`<script></script>`** Tag that's it. `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` is not a [valid HTML](https://varvy.com/valid-html-use.html) tag, so for best SEO practice use **`<script></script>`**