# min.js files are not found and their type present as to text/html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

my index file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Macabi Tel Aviv</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main" ng-view>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When im trying to run the code throgh xampp i see in the network (while debugging) that the min.js files are not found and  their type present as to text/html.... why?

p.s
in the controller files i use routing

Comment: Post the structure of your project tree.

Comment: most 404 responses are HTML flavored, so that makes sense. also, js doesn't much care about the mime anyway, so you can run js that's served as "text/html" just fine.

Comment: Angular_demo
 css
  style.css
 images
 js
  app.js
  controllers.js
  data.json
 lib
  angular
   angular.min.js
   angular-route.min.js
 partials
  list
 index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But if the file is not being find check the route, maybe it should start with "/", depending if the route shoul be relative or not

Comment: `type` is not required in html5, defaults to javascript

Comment: @charlietfl If it's an html5 thing, would it not be advisable to keep `type="text/javascript"` for older browser support? Or was it just not part of the spec before, and older browsers just defaulted to `type="text/javascript"` anyway if type was missing?

Comment: It's pretty safe to leave it out, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771400/script-tag-vs-script-type-text-javascript-tag

Comment: @DavidSpence can leave it out, has not been known to be a problem and for some reason have seen it recommended not to use it