# What difference does having attributes in the <script> tag make compared with no attributes?

Tags: javascript, attributes

**Difference From Other Questions**

I am asking what the difference is, the other questions are asking does it make a difference. I also can't relate to the answers to the other questions.

**Question**

Does having attributes in the  tag make a difference when compared to no attributes?

**Code**

Is this: `<script></script>` any different from this: `<script type = "text/javascript"></script>`?

Comment: [Other duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags) explain [what the difference is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14323399/615754) and what the `type` attribute does (or doesn't do). This has been asked lots of times [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771400/script-tag-vs-script-type-text-javascript-tag).

Comment: BTW, your example has invalid syntax. There should be no spaces around `=`.

Comment: It is not invalid, but I think it depends on what compiler you're using.