# HTML Checker shows javascript error regarding "type"

Tags: javascript, html

Being new to javascript, I am not understanding how to fix this particular error.  My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  firstName = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
  alert("Welcome to the website " + firstName +"!");
</script>
```

When I try to validate the page, I get the "warning":

```
The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.
From line 34, column 2; to line 34, column 32
<script type="text/javascript"> first
```

When I take out the word type, I get a ton of actual errors.  I've tried removing the word type and eliminating the "" from the line, but still not working without errors.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need the attribute. just `<script>....</script>`

Comment: That is too simple for words.  I would have thought I needed to leave the text/javascript part in since that is the only javascript on the page/site.

Comment: For more information see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771400/script-tag-vs-script-type-text-javascript-tag/20771411

Comment: The validator I was using I was told is the best out there -- 
https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Thanks again everyone for all the help.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<html>
...
    <script>
        firstName = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
        alert("Welcome to the website " + firstName +"!");
    </script>
...
</html>
```

This should work perfectly fine.

`type="text/javascript"` is a matter of preference.

Comment: *"`type="text/javascript` is a matter of preference."* Evidently not as the validator being used was throwing exceptions.

Comment: @Zze Evidently the writer of the validator has a preference.

Comment: @BradAnderson Is it ***very rare*** for the script tag to be used for code other than javascript. By default, all major browsers will interpret code between script tags as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the problem a bit more, the warning is quite descriptive, the type attribute is simply unnecessary.

[Douglas Crockford says](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html):

> `type="text/javascript"`
>
> This attribute is optional. Since
>   Netscape 2, the default programming
>   language in all browsers has been
>   JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute
>   is required and unnecessary. In HTML,
>   it is better to leave it out. The
>   browser knows what to do.

Sourced from an existing answer: [Why write <script type="text/javascript"> when the mime type is set by the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve)